# Why doesn't my NSMutableArray write to plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, plist

I have the following block of code:

```
NSMutableArray* mergedSymbolsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for (NSDictionary* aSymbol in localSet) {

                        NSLog(@"Symbol:%@",[aSymbol valueForKey:@"symbol"]);
                        [mergedSymbolsArray addObject:aSymbol];

                    }

                    [Utils writeObjectToPList:mergedSymbolsArray]; 
                    tickers = [Utils getDataFromPList];
```

Here is my code to read/write to a plist:

```
+ (void)writeObjectToPList:(id)myData {  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mobile-watchlist.plist"];
    [myData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}  

+(NSMutableArray*)getDataFromPList
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mobile-watchlist.plist"];

    NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"READING -- PList Data Count: %d", [myArray count]);
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

**For some reason `mergedSymbolsArray` will not write to a plist. I am not sure why?**

I am able to write the following into a plist:

```
[tickers addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"GOOG", @"symbol", @"2044", @"id", nil]];
        [tickers addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AAPL", @"symbol", @"686", @"id", nil]];
        [tickers addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YHOO", @"symbol", @"4177", @"id", nil]];

        [Utils writeObjectToPList:tickers];
```

**Why doesn't the first block of code write to a plist?**

ADDITIONAL NOTES:
Here is an example of a dictionary the mergedSymbolsArray contains:

```
  {
    "charts_count" = 2;
    "created_at" = "2010-04-12T16:37:32Z";
    exchange = NASDAQ;
    "followers_count" = 259;
    id = 8404;
    industry = "<null>";
    "messages_count" = 1436;
    ric = "GRPN.O";
    sector = "<null>";
    symbol = GRPN;
    title = Groupon;
    "updated_at" = "2011-09-05T04:17:56Z";
}
```

I am guessing the writeToFile:atomically method is failing because  cannot be written?

Comment: +(void)writeObjectToPList:(id)myData . Try changing (id) to NSMutableArray....type

Comment: @booleanboy I changed it to NSMutableArray, same results unfortunately

Comment: after adding data to mergedSymbolsArray check using NSLog to find whether data is really gettin stored....and also try using alloc instead of autorelease array...

Comment: writeToFile actually returns NO. I changed to alloc instead of autorelease, same results. Why does writeToFile return NO?

Comment: try to do it with atomically set to NO

Comment: Following what Davyd said, what kinds of objects are "created_at", "updated_at", industry, and sector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all the objects you keep in the array are the property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary).

Answer (score 2):

It fails because dta contains  sector = "<null>" whose value is interpreted as NSNull and cannot be written to a plist.

I convert NSArray or NSDictionary to NSData before serializing. Following is a category on nsarray for serializing and deserializing. This comfortableby handles some data being nsnull

```
-(BOOL)writeToPlistFile:(NSString*)filename{
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    BOOL didWriteSuccessfull = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    return didWriteSuccessfull;
}

+(NSArray*)readFromPlistFile:(NSString*)filename{
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really fixed my problem :)
I missed the NSKeyedArchiver, I think I'll read more about it soon isA :)
Thanks for your help again :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `[myData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];` please. If it's NO, some errors have occurred while writing.Try to alloc-init the NSMutableArray instead of creating an autoreleased one.

Comment: I checked if writeToFile:atomically returned correctly. Unfortunately it returns NO for my case. How can I diagnose further?

Comment: @Sheehan what is the value of path when writeToFile: is getting called? Does the directory exist?

Comment: The directory does exist. The value of path is `/Users/syalam/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/2C2B2FDF-B376-43FA-AA95-49921B3DC3B4/Documents/mobile-watchlist.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash to your file name Ie:

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/mobile-watchlist.plist"];
```

Comment: `stringByAppendingPathComponent` does it automatically

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem. Still can't write plist